# Track number of user redirected via google ads

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, pay-per-click

Is there any way to check an user is redirected to my site via Google Ads?

[image]

I want to track number of user who are redirected via Google Ads and their activities.
I have Google Analytics, Adword added already to my website.
I can track users on my site via Google Analytics only.

Answer (score 0):

You can [link your AdWords account to your Analytics account](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961?hl=en-GB).  Once you have done this, you will be able to see how many users came via AdWords in the "AdWords" section of the Acquisition area of Analytics.  You'll see which campaigns & ads the users clicked, what key words they used and so on.  You can then do all the usual GA filtering and grouping with that data that you usually can with normal visit info.

Hope that helps.